# Realtek ethernet can ping on embedded Linux but nothing else works

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, ethernet

I am running an embedded system (i.MX6 Quad), Yocto Dunfell Linux on a 5.10.54 mainline kernel.  I am trying to make an mPCIe Realtek ethernet card work (it has a Realtek 8111 chip on it; I have tried two slightly different mPCIe cards thus far).  From a hardware perspective, the hardware has been validated by NXP contractors.

I have turned on all the Realtek kernel configs, and the device shows up in `ifconfig`.  I can set an address (via `ifconfig enp1s0 10.0.0.100`) and have it ping out.  The ping output is weird:

```
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=23 ttl=128 time=0.434 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=24 ttl=128 time=0.362 ms
[  108.012067] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=25 ttl=128 time=7026.885 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=26 ttl=128 time=6026.852 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=27 ttl=128 time=5026.850 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=28 ttl=128 time=4026.811 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=29 ttl=128 time=3026.843 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=30 ttl=128 time=2026.811 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=31 ttl=128 time=1026.832 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=32 ttl=128 time=26.821 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=33 ttl=128 time=0.430 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=34 ttl=128 time=0.410 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=35 ttl=128 time=0.382 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=36 ttl=128 time=0.439 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=37 ttl=128 time=0.416 ms
[  119.787506] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=38 ttl=128 time=5801.290 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=39 ttl=128 time=4801.276 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=40 ttl=128 time=3801.297 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=41 ttl=128 time=2801.307 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=42 ttl=128 time=1801.293 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=43 ttl=128 time=801.302 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=44 ttl=128 time=0.396 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=45 ttl=128 time=0.443 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=46 ttl=128 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=47 ttl=128 time=0.431 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=48 ttl=128 time=0.421 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=49 ttl=128 time=0.432 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=50 ttl=128 time=0.432 ms
[  136.171503] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=57 ttl=128 time=3184.353 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=58 ttl=128 time=2184.399 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=59 ttl=128 time=1184.373 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=60 ttl=128 time=184.371 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=61 ttl=128 time=0.442 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.249: seq=62 ttl=128 time=0.453 ms
```

If I try to run something like iperf, it makes the connection and tries to run, but I get 0 bits transferred.

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-23.50  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-23.50  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  receiver
```

I cannot SSH into it, even though SSH is enabled (and works on the main board's non-PCIe ethernet).

Looking into the driver, I don't see a printout for `rtl_rxtx_empty_cond`, but the places that is used don't seem to be an error (I am a noob at driver development though).  There is however a crash that looks relevant in dmesg:

```
[  941.365350] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  986.078679] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  986.078726] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:467 dev_watchdog+0x250/0x254
[  986.078739] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp1s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[  986.078755] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W         5.10.54 #1
[  986.078770] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[  986.078812] [<c010c914>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c01096f0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[  986.078835] [<c01096f0>] (show_stack) from [<c08ae808>] (dump_stack+0x98/0xac)
[  986.078855] [<c08ae808>] (dump_stack) from [<c08a201c>] (__warn+0xbc/0xd4)
[  986.078870] [<c08a201c>] (__warn) from [<c08a20b8>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x84/0x98)
[  986.078887] [<c08a20b8>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c074b6f8>] (dev_watchdog+0x250/0x254)
[  986.078911] [<c074b6f8>] (dev_watchdog) from [<c0174568>] (call_timer_fn.constprop.0+0x24/0x98)
[  986.078929] [<c0174568>] (call_timer_fn.constprop.0) from [<c0174c8c>] (run_timer_softirq+0x46c/0x480)
[  986.078943] [<c0174c8c>] (run_timer_softirq) from [<c010132c>] (__do_softirq+0x104/0x274)
[  986.078961] [<c010132c>] (__do_softirq) from [<c011bd6c>] (irq_exit+0xac/0xd4)
[  986.078976] [<c011bd6c>] (irq_exit) from [<c015b294>] (__handle_domain_irq+0x60/0xb0)
[  986.078995] [<c015b294>] (__handle_domain_irq) from [<c049ea50>] (gic_handle_irq+0x80/0x94)
[  986.079010] [<c049ea50>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0100b0c>] (__irq_svc+0x6c/0xa8)
[  986.079020] Exception stack(0xc0d01ed8 to 0xc0d01f20)
[  986.079028] 1ec0:                                                       00000000 000000e5
[  986.079048] 1ee0: 2acaf000 eb98ff80 c0d0ae48 00000000 eb98f350 00000000 00000000 96de3005
[  986.079059] 1f00: 000000e5 000000e5 fffffff5 c0d01f28 c067fd24 c067fd44 600f0013 ffffffff
[  986.079078] [<c0100b0c>] (__irq_svc) from [<c067fd44>] (cpuidle_enter_state+0x168/0x364)
[  986.079093] [<c067fd44>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<c067ff7c>] (cpuidle_enter+0x28/0x38)
[  986.079109] [<c067ff7c>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<c013edbc>] (do_idle+0x1c0/0x220)
[  986.079123] [<c013edbc>] (do_idle) from [<c013f0f0>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x18/0x1c)
[  986.079141] [<c013f0f0>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<c0c00df8>] (start_kernel+0x43c/0x454)
[  986.079154] ---[ end trace 63de1e23186ea13d ]---
[  986.092117] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
[ 1002.475338] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
[ 1013.227687] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
[ 1035.243335] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: rtl_rxtx_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 42, delay: 100).
```

If you look at the initialization of the device in dmesg, I thought the irq=IGNORE was a bit strange, but I don't know how to change that.

```
[    1.198854] r8169 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0143)
[    1.206722] libphy: r8169: probed
[    1.207175] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth1: RTL8168h/8111h, 00:13:3b:5a:0d:0d, XID 541, IRQ 315
[    1.207189] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth1: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    4.831518] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth1
[   57.275775] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-100:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-100:00, irq=IGNORE)
[   57.483907] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
[   61.187478] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
```

I am at a loss on how to fix this or even what the root cause of the issue is.  Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: There's a [kernel.org bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209839) about  something very similar, if not identical, which includes a patch. Apparently it was fixed in kernel 5.10.2 but maybe not in NXP's version, if they maintain a fork.

Comment: I am running mainline, not the NXP branch.  I have most of those changes, and while my `rtl8125_quirk_udp_padto` function doesn't match either side of that diff, it does have length checking in it.  I have all the other changes in that patch.

Comment: for what it is worth, I also tried adding a few sleeps in the power up sequence (as mentioned here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199549)  and tried this change to no avail: https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/unstable/commit/?id=759bc16ddfd4d7f3e195a9662d9d067625b805b6